# CSP url-scheme http:// matches if resource's scheme is either http:// or https://

Tags: security, iframe, specifications, content-security-policy

Let's take the frame-ancestors directive. Say I want to allow `http://*.parent.com` to load my page at both `https://child.com` and `http://child.com`:

1. If I set `frame-ancestors https://*.parent.com` we have an obvious violation
2. If I set `frame-ancestors *.parent.com` we have a violation for `https://child.com`.
3. If I set `frame-ancestors http://*.parent.com` it works for both cases. Why ?

Quoting from the [CSP2 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#match-source-expression):

> 4. If the source expression has a scheme-part that is not a case insensitive match for url-scheme, then return does not match.
> 5. If the source expression does not have a scheme, return does not match if any of the following are true:
>
>    1. the scheme of the protected resource’s URL is a case insensitive match for HTTP, and url-scheme is not a case insensitive match for either HTTP or HTTPS
>    2. the scheme of the protected resource’s URL is not a case insensitive match for HTTP, and url-scheme is not a case insensitive match for the scheme of the protected resource’s URL.

Case 2 of my examples must choke according to condition 5.2 of the spec since `https://child.com` is not a match for HTTP, that I understand.
But why does case 3 work for `https://child.com`? According to condition 4 it should fail since `http://*.parent.com` does not match the scheme of `https://child.com`. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

**Objective**

Allow `http://*.parent.com` to load my page at both `https://child.com` and `http://child.com`

**Case 3**

CSP policy on `child.com`:

```
frame-ancestors http://*.parent.com
```

> But why does case 3 work for https://child.com?

If you browse to, e.g. `http://1.parent.com`, which iframes some `child.com` content, e.g.:

```
<iframe src="https://child.com/mycontent">
```

....then `child.com` checks its CSP `frame-ancestors` expression against the URL requesting `/mycontent`, viz:

`http://1.parent.com` is compared to `http://*.parent.com`, which matches, so `/mycontent` is successfully returned.

> According to condition 4 it should fail since http://*.parent.com does
>   not match the scheme of https://child.com. What am I missing ?

It sounds a bit like you may be misunderstanding `frame-ancestors`. In your example, there wouldn't be any checks against `https://child.com`. The check is *made by* `child.com`, comparing the URL requesting `/mycontent` to `http://*.parent.com`. Perhaps you're confusing `frame-ancestors` with `frame-src`?

As for the spec, I found it very difficult to understand, but fortunately I found [this very helpful page](https://scotthelme.co.uk/safari-doesnt-like-csp/) which translates it into something more readily understandable. I'll quote the relevant bit:

> 5 - If the whitelisted host in the CSP does not have a scheme, the browser is allowed to:
>
> 1 - Loads assets using HTTP or HTTPS if the page is served using HTTP.
>
> 2 - Loads assets using HTTPS if the page is served using HTTPS.

From all the reading around I've done, omitting the URL scheme from the CSP expression *should* work to allow both `http` and `https` requests, implicitly. But in practice, with  `frame-ancestors`, it hasn't worked for me....at all....and that's consistent across browsers too.

So, my practical experience of using CSP `frame-ancestors` has led me to believe that in order to grant access to sites so that they may iframe *my* site's content, I need to prefix the domain with the URL scheme in my site's CSP `frame-ancestors` expression.

Typically I would want to allow both `http` and `https`, therefore I would need, e.g.:

```
frame-ancestors http://*.parent.com https://*.parent.com
```